# Активация формы в Delphi

Tags: delphi

В общем такой вопрос (чужой код). Есть приложение, в котором есть 2 формы: TForm1, TForm4.
По умолчанию активная TForm4. Нужно убить TForm4, и активировать TForm1 со всеми элементами.

Answer (score 1):

Найти и закрыть окно по заголовку:

```
var wnd:HWND:
begin
wnd:=FindWindow(nil, 'заголовок окна т.е. формы4');
if wnd<>0 then PostMessage(wnd, MW_QUIT, 1, 0);
end;
```

Найти активное окно и закрыть его:

```
var wnd:HWND:
begin
wnd:=GetForegroundWindow();
if wnd<>0 then PostMessage(wnd, MW_QUIT, 1, 0);
end;
```

Comment: Вряд ли ему это поможет, ему нужно активировать первую форму, и её не видно, скорее всего 4 форма просит ключ, а его нет

Comment: правильно думаешь, ключ бил изменен из за того замены железа, вот теперь проблемы...

Comment: Я вчера писал пришли мне на почту r-soft@ukr.net программу посмотрю что можно сделать.

Comment: отослал

Answer (score 0):

Если исходники у Вас то смотрите как TForm4 становится активной,
а вообще все это можно поправить или в DPR или project->Options->Forms

Comment: Программа не моя. исходника нету. поэтому надо удаленно закрыть форму4 и открыть форму1.

Comment: Это я так понимаю взлом.
Дизасемблер вам в помощь.

Comment: что то вроде этого. программа написана на делфи так что с дизасемблером не поиграешься. на нее уже делали кряк и он просто активировал форму, но он утерялся.

Comment: Первое не видя программы что то подсказать сложно.
Второе кто вам сказал что дизасемблер не поможет?
Третье если форма называется TForm это не обязательно Delphi
Четвертое вполне возможно что с 4 формы передаются еще и параметры какие то так что простая активация тут может не помочь.

Comment: 1. программа написана на делфи это 100% так как я знаком с автором програмы. 2. без понятия. 3.у вас есть icq\skype?

Comment: Напиши на r-soft@ukr.net

Comment: Вообще-то программы созданные в дельфи и билдере обладают достаточно регулярной структурой. К тому же эти компиляторы генерируют rtti-информацию. Поэтому возможно создание дизассемблера таких программ и он существует. Можно скачать с сайта cracklab. Название программы, увы, утерял, но найдете ее легко. Так же хочу отметить из ее функционала возможность выдирать формы из исполняемого файла....

Answer (score 0):

Если в форме есть какой-нибудь элемент, то лови форму по элементу, можно по Имени Кнопки или Edit'у или ещё чему. Имена элементов можешь увидеть через WinSight (приложение в пакете Delphi) эта софтина показывает инфу о скрытых и явных формах запущенных в ОЗУ. Перехватишь по элементу, а там и кнопку нажать сможешь или MW_QUIT послать. Там уже на усмотрение.